# GKE pod to another cluster (internal loadbalancer) communication via TCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Hello I'm trying to determine why my pods in another cluster can't communicate via AMQP (TCP) to an internal GCP loadbalancer that sits in another cluster.

Pod to pod (from cluster to cluster) works, and the internal LB pulls a valid internal ip that can be accessed via GCE VMs. Just struggling with the above issue:

I've attached a diagram to get my point across:

Things I've tried:
Creating my own L4 Loadbalancer
Using GKE's internal Ingress with NEG for layer 7 (this method only works for http/ https and not AMQP (TCP)).

Sample deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: rabbitmq
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          value: guest
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
          value: guest
        image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: rabbitmq
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: Internal
    networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-allow-global-access: 'true'
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: rabbitmq
  name: expose-rabbitmq
spec:
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 10.150.0.0/16
  ports:
  - name: epmd
    port: 4369
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: epmd
  - name: amqp
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp
  - name: dist
    port: 25672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: dist
  - name: stats
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: stats
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: rabbitmq
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: diagram found here: https://i.imgur.com/nilNBRQ.png

Comment: are both clusters in same region ?

Comment: Do you have the right firewall rules to allow the communication? Also, can you reach some pod/service of cluster 2 from cluster 1?

Comment: @TarunKhosla yes both clusters sit on the same region and on the same vpc network and subnet

Comment: @KoopaKiller yes, pods from one cluster can reach pods in another cluster, firewall rules have been set to allow traffic from the cidr range of the pods to communicate to the vpc subnet

Comment: Have you tried to use nginx-ingress instead gke ingress? Because gke ingress is Layer 7, nginx-ingress on GKE creates a Layer 4 load balancer to permit tcp traffic. Please share the yamls fule, if you could,  or a minimal example to reproduce and i can test in my account

Comment: @KoopaKiller just updated my question with sample yaml files. Please try to curl the internal loadbalancer via port 15672 from another cluster in the same gcp project/ region/ vpc subnet. I'll take a look into deploying nginx-ingress and see if that helps.

Comment: @AnewKoo Any progress with nginx-ingress?

Comment: @KoopaKiller nginx-ingress work in my environment but only for http/https. I'm looking for something for generic TCP connections (AMQP/5672).

Comment: @AnewKoo you can use nginx-ingress to tcp connection, see this [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

Comment: @KoopaKiller installed nginx-ingress through https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml, as well as the helm3 chart. The TCP passthrough works via 80 and 5672 from GCE VMs --> GKE, but GKE --> GKE still times out.